# Can't identification variable on partial files that import by partial files

Tags: css, variables, sass

When I import partial files on style.scss. It's working fine. All variables working fine.

**style.scss**

```
@import 'base/variable';

//Component
@import 'component/menubar';
@import 'component/menubar-mascot';
@import 'component/menubar-count';
@import 'component/menubar-button';
```

But when I try to merge menubar scss partial files, like this

**style.scss**

```
@import 'base/variable';

//Component
@import 'component/menubar';
```

**menubar.scss**

```
@import 'menubar-mascot';
@import 'menubar-count';
@import 'menubar-button';
```

The variable on `variable.scss` it cannot readable, but when I import again the `variable.scss` on `menubar.scss`, like this

**menubar.scss**

```
@import '../base/variable';
@import 'menubar-mascot';
@import 'menubar-count';
@import 'menubar-button';
```

it's working fine, why? and how to fix this without import again the `variables.scss` on `menubar.scss`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume menubar-mascot is located where you ran the sass command.
For some reason absolute path in nested imports doesn't seem to be found.

```
@import 'menubar-mascot';
@import 'menubar-count';
@import 'menubar-button';
```

However if you use a relative one it does find it. So relative to your bundle scss file you can do:

```
@import '../menubar-mascot';
@import '../menubar-count';
@import '../menubar-button';
```

Thus it will go back from component folder back to the root and find the correct files.

Comment: Good answer but it doesn't help me, I have done with import the menubar-mascot, etc. files, but my problem is that variable is undefined on my menubar-mascot

Comment: @EngkusKusnadi I tried your exact setup and this is what made it work...Can you please post your directory setup ? Like a picture of the files